# What is WEBAPP_HOST in web hook?

Tags: server, webserver, hosting, telegram-bot, aiogram

I'm trying to deploy my Telegram Bot on hosting. The bot was written in python, aiogram.
Firstly, for a test I tried to deploy simple echo bot.
According to [aiogram docs](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html):

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://your.domain'    # Here I entered my domain
WEBHOOK_PATH = f'/{API_TOKEN}'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"

# webserver settings
WEBAPP_HOST = 'localhost'  # THIS IS QUESTION, I do not know what to enter here.
WEBAPP_PORT = 3001
```

I do not know what to enter to WEBAPP_HOST. I tried enter "localhost", "0.0.0.0", site's domain, and site's ip address, but none of them worked.
What should I write there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the FQDN of your webserver where you host the script that you've set up as the webhook.

So if your webhook script is hosted on `https://example.com/telegram/webhook.py`, you'll need the following settings:

```
WEBHOOK_HOST = 'https://example.com'
WEBHOOK_PATH = '/telegram/webhook.py'
WEBHOOK_URL = f"{WEBHOOK_HOST}{WEBHOOK_PATH}"
```